# Simple css with boostrap to create single vertically aligned div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I always seem to run into this same problem which I think is a bit of a gap in my CSS knowledge. I'm using bootstrap but any particular best method would be fine. I simply want to create something similar to this:

```
<table style="height:100%; width:100%">
<tr style="height:15%"><td></td></tr>
<tr style="height:70%; background-color:#EAB300; text-align:center;"><td>Main</td></tr>
<tr style="height:15%"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c24hd/

But with divs rather than tables. It takes seconds to do with a table but when I replicate it with divs I run into the trouble of not being able to apply a percent based height to divs.

Any tips so I can stop running into this problem?

TIA

Comment: `div`s with a table layout should work the way you're describing. What have you tried with `div`s?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a `<div>` and set the height to 100%.  Then set the inner `<div>` margins to auto.

EDIT: Never mind that, the best is way is to display the div as a table and the inner div as a table cell then vertical-align it.

EDIT: One more, you can even use absolute positioning to center it on the screen.